# java 1.7 - how to read same data on different position using same code/method

Tags: java, while-loop

I have an while operator that reading data,

```
int typeArr =0 ;
int newObj = 0;
int  name = 0;
while((Name =readInt()) != 0x00) {
    int info = in.readUnsignedByte();
    int Type = in.readUnsignedByte();
    if(PropertySizeType == 1) {
        typeArr = in.readUnsignedByte();
        for (int k = 0; k < typeArr; k++) {
            newObj = in.readUnsignedByte();
        }
    }
 }
```

Problem is that after i readed newObj value, i need to move to that position - like that

```
in.seek(newObj);
```

after that i need to repeat the same process as i did in the above(while ...)
How can i do that ?

Comment: sorry but you deleted important info ? didnt you see that ? i can beautify the code by my own.

Comment: what do you mean about instance foor loop ? can you explain a bit ? or send me a link

Comment: [K & R Code Conventions, indentation](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style)

Comment: ehmm does look nasty =( , is there any way of avoiding - creating new classes, or voids ?

Comment: @LightFusion what is the type of newObj. keep in mind that an Integer is represented by 4 bytes.

Comment: @Dien its same data as above, new obj its just a pointer, where the reading should occure again ! I wont to avoid using voids, if its possible ?

Comment: Please clarify: what do you mean by "avoid using voids"? You're also reading in a bunch of `newObjs` in your for loop -- so which one should be used re-set `in`? I'm not sure about the others, but I'm really not clear on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @LightFusion is "in" a short for Inputstream

Comment: i mean that i can put this code from my void method, to void names TypeObjects(){} - and return it, when i need, but i dont want to use this method - is there any other ?   Yeah im reading bounch cause it loops in a while, but does this matter ? i want to know how can i read new data on differnt position, using same code inside my method(Void).

Comment: @Dien in is RandomAccessFile.

Comment: @Dient - im not doing any special, i have object(A) on certain pointer(in Data/file), inside of Object(A), are structured data properties and a link to object(B),pointer on place inside of Data/File, with same data Structure as Object(A), i just dont want to use void for it ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the function from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29)

```
  while((Name =readInt()) != 0x00)
{
   try{

     int info = in.readUnsignedByte();
     int Type = in.readUnsignedByte();
      if(PropertySizeType == 1) {
    typeArr = in.readUnsignedByte();
    for (int k = 0; k < typeArr; k++) {
        newObj = in.readUnsignedByte();
        in.seek(newObj);  // newObj should be a long
       }
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
         break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: ? what the point of doing it, if i need to read the data (that has same type, described in code above) ? ehmm seems i'l have to create while loop with same code ...

Comment: I'm glad that you understand what the problem is, Dien, because I'm still completely lost.

Comment: @Dien, its not helping, because first data is on in.seek(1000), but newObj is on(2000), if i seek to newObj Too early, while Name!= 0x00, i endup reading not all objects.

Comment: @LightFusion what do you mean by first data ?

Comment: @Dien,First Data has an array of objects, that is getted readed by readInt(), while there is no 0x00, if it find it - it stops.                               if i seek - i didnt read some part of it. if i make something like this `if(PropertyName==0x00){in.seek(ArrayObjType);
       continue;}` i read only first data ;

Comment: @LightFusion ok.Did you notice that I updated my answer. Did you use  skipBytes() or seek().

Comment: i use seek(to get to the first data).

Comment: So you use seek for the first. then you loop to find the remaining data. Do you use seek as well ?

Comment: @Dien i need to seek to remaining data only when - all objects from first are readed, - how can i store count of my variable Name,that is used in while ! without array ?

Comment: @LightFusion you can use an ArrayList instead. It does not require setting an initial size.

Comment: @Dient like so `List<Integer> PropertyName = new ArrayList<Integer>();` , `while((PropertyName =readCompactInt()) != 0x00) //`  if i use it like that i get error - 
Incompatible operand types List<Integer> and int

Comment: @Dien but how am i check whether is empty(0x00) or not ? if i use ToArray, it checks only if its not null, but 0x00 mean for it a not null too

Comment: PropertyName.add(readCompactInt()); while(PropertyName.get(PropertyName.size()-1) != 0x00)